# Type checks with runtypes

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, types, runtypes

I'm trying to validate a configuration part of an object with [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) using [pelotom/runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes) library; but I receive the error "expected false to be true":

```
//>>>>> declaration:
export const PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType = Record({
    plugin_configuration: Record({
        type: Literal("plugin_configuration_not_required")
    })
});

export type PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType = Static<
    typeof PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType
>;


//>>>>> the object to test: I want to test only the "plugin_configuration" part; it must be with type: "plugin_configuration_not_required":
{test:{
plugin_configuration: {
            type: "plugin_configuration_not_required"
        },
value: 1}
}

//>>>>> the test:
it("should use a valid plugin not required configuration", () => {
    const config = getConfiguration();
    expect(
        PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType.validate(config.plugin_configuration)
            .success
    ).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that I believe that this is happening is that you're testing the "inner" property of the type/object against its wrapper.

I haven't tested this but doing this should work:

```
PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType.validate(config);
```

Alternatively, if you want to test the inner property then you can declare 2 runtypes at the top of that example like this:

```
const PluginConfigurationInner = Record({
    type: Literal("plugin_configuration_not_required")
});
export const PluginConfigurationNotRequiredType = Record({
    plugin_configuration: PluginConfigurationInner
});
```

Then your test code would use the first "Record" declaration for its test:

```
PluginConfigurationInner.validate(config.plugin_configuration);
```